# extra content class in modal

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to create and design a modal with specific properties.
but for some reason i am getting 2 modal contents divs.
one with the desierd properties and another one with the default properties.
and i do not understand where it's coming from.

```
  <ng-template #contents let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
       <div class="modal-body">
         ...
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         ...
       </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

now when i am viewing this modal in the browser this is what presented to the user :
[image]

and this is what is see in dev tools :

[image]

the div with the modal-content class is that extra modal in the background.

from where it is coming from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you hover on the element in Chrome dev tools, the element in the browser is highlighted in blue. I wonder if the modal-content is that extra white background, why it is not highlighted?

Comment: It was highlighted, when i activated the screen capture it was gone

Comment: Does the code outside <ng-template> has modal content too? Try using <ng-container> instead.

Comment: no.it dose not had that class.and i tried to change it to container,still get the same issue